# cannot read property 'value' of null after adding HTML and some JSP code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jsp

I got a task to add 2 dropdown menu in html, which are "issuer" and "product code".

Beside that, I have to add a value shown as "All" as default (in order to show all options available in each dropdown menu).

```
<option value=0>All</option>
```

After I click Report, the Error shows like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOAqe.png).

Finally, the codes using `.jsp` :

```
     <p align=center>
            <table width="100%" align=center><tr><td>
            <table align=center>
                <tr> 
                <td  align=right>
                Issuer</td>
                <td >
                <select name=IssuerID id=IssuerID onchange="this.form.action='ReportTransaction.jsp';this.form.submit();">
        <option value=0>All</option>
        <% ... some jsp codes here ...%>
        <option value=<% ... jsp codes here ... %></option>
                </select>
                </td>
                </tr>       
                <tr> 
                <td  align=right>
                Product Code</td>
                <td >
                <select name=vProductCode id=vProductCode onchange="this.form.action='ReportTransaction.jsp';this.form.submit();">
        <option value=0>All</option>
                </select>
                </td>
                </tr>       

<% ... jsp codes here ...%>         

       <option value=<% ... jsp codes here ... %></option>
<% ... jsp codes here ... %>

                </select>
                </td>
                </tr>
                <td>
                Earliest Date</td>
                <td >
        <input type="text" maxlength="10" name="Edate" id="Edate" value="<%=currentDate%>" style="width:100px;">&nbsp;(DD/MM/YYYY)
                </td>
                </tr>         
                <tr> 
                <td>
                Latest Date</td>
                <td >
        <input type="text" maxlength="10" name="LDate" id="LDate" value="<%=currentDate%>" style="width:100px;">&nbsp;(DD/MM/YYYY)
                </td>
                </tr>         
                <tr>
                <td>
                Transaction Type
                </td>
                <td >
                <select name=vTransType id=vTransType onChange="addTransaction(this.form,this);">
        <option value=0>All</option>
<% ... jsp codes here ... %>
        <option value=<% ... some jsp codes here ... %>                                                        </option>
<% ... jsp codes here ... %>
                </select>
                </td>
                </tr>

More and more codes below..
```

The question is:

1. Does the error shown is because I add the value `<option value=0>All</option>` ?
2. How can I find / trace the root of this error type? Like "error in line 76" or "error occured at file Transaction.jsp". I did thoroughly searched for an answer, but it still didn't solve my code problem.

Enlighten me, Captain!

Comment: A part of your html seems incorrect and this could give unexpected behaviour, <option value=<% ... jsp codes here ... %></option> would be <option value=<% ... jsp codes here ... %>></option>

Comment: Sorry, I did a mistake in editing, the correct one is like your explanation, <option value=<% ... jsp codes here ... %>></option>